# Best way to create views based on a theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create separate view pages for a controller that I have.

I have a CustomerController that, based on the customer I need to create custom pages, these pages have to be stored as a file not from the db.

So normally I would have this:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(param["id"])
  end
end
```

And the views would be located at:

```
/views/customer/show.html.erb
```

What I want to do is have the view pages like:

```
/views/customer/1/show.html.erb
/views/customer/2/show.html.erb
/views/customer/3/show.html.erb
```

How can I reference the specific view pages to load from within the action?
Is there a way to just pass the value 1,2,3 to the view folder path?

Comment: Is the folder number also the Id of the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a template to render in the show action. Rails, without you explicitly calling `render`, will render the template that corresponds to that specific action...so, in your case, it will automatically render customers/show.html.erb (Note: Your controller should be plural...ie CustomersController, not CustomerController)

To override this, you can do something like this

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  render "customers/#{@customer.id}/show.html.erb"
end
```